# Angular2 Data binding for Primeng autocomplete component

Tags: angular, primeng

Am using `Angular2: 2.1.0` and `Primeng: 1.0.0`,

I want `Autocomplete` component to bind to my `object's key` and show `object's value` in UI.

**Here the Object is**,

```
[{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "John"
},
{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "Ganesh"
},
{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "Irfan"
}]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p-autoComplete  [(ngModel)]="userId" placeholder="User Search..." field="user_name" [suggestions]="suggestionList"  (completeMethod)="userSearch($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

Using `field` attribute in autocomplete i can show my `object's value` in UI screen, but the entire object is binded to `userId`

How can i make binding `user_id` of selected object to `userId` ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and actually ended using a separate method to capture the value

```
captureId(event: any) {
    this.userId = event.user_id;
}
```

And the actual use

```
<p-autoComplete (onSelect)="captureId($event)" ...
```

Comment: Hi Blazej, t is not working for me..
When i start typing `Jho` userId also have value of 'Jho'. 
if i select `Jhon` in the suggestion list userId remains 'Jho' and its not changed to 101
(input) event is not triggering when i select one of from user suggession list.

Comment: I've corrected my anwser not to use ngModel, can you please try now?

Comment: Getting error, `Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-autoComplete'.`

Comment: Hi NTN-JAVA, sorry for the confusion, I've tested it again, rolled back to ngModel and plugged in the onSelect event that was missing. This could be simplified if you don't want to capture the user's input (like when he enters any texts and submits form) just to cover the selection.

Comment: Hi Blazej, Good to see you again,
This shows `user_id` in UI instead of `user_name` after choosing user in suggession list.
If you removed `[ngModel]="userId"` from ur answer then it is what exactly we want :-).
But the problem is edit screen may not have `user_name` in autocomplete box bcz i removed `[ngModel]="userId"`.

Comment: @ Blazej, it is partially done. but we yet to cover showing username in autocomplete box while editing user.
i meant by editing user is "feeding userobject to autocomplete box".
there is no `ngModel` is here so neither `user_id` nor `user_name` in autocomplete box.
Remember the dropdown component shows the `user_name` in selected state by default.

Answer (score 1):

@NTN-JAVA I have done this my using field property.

```html
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="userName" [suggestions]="filteredBrands" name="guestType"
(completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="12" [minLength]="1" field="user_name" inputStyleClass="txt-box" placeholder="Hint: type 'v' or 'f'" [dropdown]="true" (onDropdownClick)="handleDropdownClick($event)">
 </p-autoComplete>
```

```js
  guestDetails =
    
    [{
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "John"
    },
    {
        "user_id": 102,
        "user_name": "Ganesh"
    },
    {
        "user_id": 103,
        "user_name": "Irfan"
    }]

    **Javascript**
    
        handleDropdownClick() {
            this.filteredBrands = [];
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.filteredBrands = guestDetails;
              
            }, 100);
          }
```

Comment: what is the value of `reservationDetails.guestType` for u?

Comment: it is binding to `{
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "John"
    }` not with 101.

Comment: @NTN-JAVA that is my model name for 2 way binding from component.I have updated my post with proper data.

Comment: ,I think u misunderstand my question.
i want to bind with user_id(ie.101 not entire user object) where as suggestion list should show `user_name`.
Simply the way we used `label` and `name` for drop down component.
In ur case the entire user object will be in `userName`

Comment: @NTN-JAVA ya got your question now. I will come up with working answer.

Comment: @NTN-JAVA I have explicitly getting the value when I submit my form save(model , isValid: boolean) {
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(model.value.userName.user_id);
 
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

Comment: Yes.. but is there any way to bind a data using a method call ?
So that i can write my `user_id` capturing logic over there and bind `user_id` it to model object.

Comment: No. Not able to find any such things. If I get anything I will make sure to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my understanding of the question and discussion so far:

- the autocomplete gives us a User as model
- but what we want is user_id
- basically, we need a "model mapping" from User to user_id and also the other way around (if our model is initialized with a user_id, the according User should be pre-selected in the auto-complete )

This can be achieved in a generic way by wrapping the ControlValueAccessor interface that autocomplete (and all other input components in angular) implements.  This wrapper can do the transformation.
ngModel, formControl or formControlName directive is then used on the wrapper.

I have created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DsM74QuGyFMVK0vF1oQs?p=preview) to show this approach. It uses "Country" instead of "User":

```
<control-value-mapper [formControl]="control" [toModel]="idOfCountry" [fromModel]="countryForId" >
      <p-autoComplete #cvDelegate

        [suggestions]="results" 
        (completeMethod)="search($event)" 
        field="name"
        dataKey="id">

      </p-autoComplete>
</control-value-mapper>
```

The ControlValueMapper looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'control-value-mapper',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => ControlValueMapper),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class ControlValueMapper implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ContentChild('cvDelegate')
  delegate: ControlValueAccessor

  @Input()
  fromModel: (any) => any;

  @Input()
  toModel: (any) => any;

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.delegate.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any) {
    this.delegate.writeValue(this.fromModel(obj));  
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any)  {
    this.delegate.registerOnChange(value => fn(this.toModel(value)));
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any)  {
    this.delegate.registerOnTouched(value => fn(this.toModel(value)));
  }
}
```

"toModel" and "fromModel" are the functions that map from Country to its id and vice versa.

Note that this solution is probably 'longer' than others, but it can be re-used in all similar situations (with other input components than autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution an year ago and updating my answer for others.
As `stefan's` answer we need model mapping, but his answer looks large process.

I used primeng autocomplete component and created a own component called `user-search` with `@Input()` and `@Output()` events.

Template (**user.search.component.html**)

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="userObject" placeholder="User Search..." field="user_name" [suggestions]="userSuggesstionList"
 (onSelect)="onUserSelect($event)" (completeMethod)="search($event)">
</p-autoComplete>
```

Component (**UserSearchComponent** ),

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-search',
    templateUrl: 'user.search.component.html'
})
export class UserSearchComponent implements OnInit {
   userSuggesstionList: any[] = [];
    userObject: any;
    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    // note that this must be named as the input model name + "Change"
    @Output() userSelected: any = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() userIdChange: any = new EventEmitter();
    @Input()
    set userId(userId: string) {
        if (userId != null && userId != '') {
            this.userObject = // Load user object from local cache / from service.
        } else {
            this.userObject = null;
        }
    }

    get userId(): string {
        if (this.userObject != null) {
            return this.userObject.userId;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    search(event) {
        // your search logic.
    }

    onUserSelect(event) {
        this.userIdChange.emit(event.userId);
        this.userSelected.emit(event);
    }
}
```

And the usage of user-search component is,

```
<user-search [(userId)]="user_id"></user-search>
```

Here the user_id given as input to `user-search` component, `user-search` component loads actual user object from cache/ from server as based on `user_id`. once the user object gets loaded then `p-autocomplete` will bind with `userObject` and displayed the username in autocomplete box.

Once user selected from suggestion list, A default change event is triggered to update `user_id` value in parent component.

Also you can avail the UserObject ie. {user_id: 'xxx', user_name:'xxx'} in `userSelected` event.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply wrap primeNG's autocomplete inside a custom autocomplete component that implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

The custom component will customize the data binding if a `dataKey` is defined as an `@Input` or keeps primeNG's default behavior if no `dataKey` is defined.

In the following code I use only properties and events I need, but it can be applied to all properties and events provided by primeNG's API.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<p-autoComplete (completeMethod)="completeMethod.emit($event)"
                (onClear)="onClear.emit($event)"
                (onDropdownClick)="onDropdownClick.emit($event)"
                (onSelect)="select($event)"
                [dataKey]="dataKey"
                [delay]="delay"
                [disabled]="disabled"
                [dropdown]="dropdown"
                [emptyMessage]="emptyMessage"
                [field]="field"
                [forceSelection]="forceSelection"
                [maxlength]="maxLength"
                [minLength]="minLength"
                [multiple]="multiple"
                [placeholder]="placeholder"
                [readonly]="readonly"
                [required]="required"
                [styleClass]="styleClass"
                [suggestions]="suggestions"
                [unique]="unique"
                [(ngModel)]="autoCompleteValue">
</p-autoComplete>
```

And here is the typescript code :

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'mb-auto-complete',
    templateUrl: './auto-complete.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./auto-complete.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutoCompleteComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() dataKey: string = null;
    @Input() delay: number = 300;
    @Input() disabled: boolean;
    @Input() dropdown: boolean = false;
    @Input() emptyMessage: string = null;
    @Input() field: any = null;
    @Input() forceSelection: boolean = null;
    @Input() maxLength: number = null;
    @Input() minLength: number = 1;
    @Input() multiple: boolean = false;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() readonly: boolean = false;
    @Input() required: boolean = false;
    @Input() styleClass: string = null;
    @Input() suggestions: any[] = [];
    @Input() unique: boolean = true;
    @Output() completeMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() onClear: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() onDropdownClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    private onChange = (value: any): void => { /**/ };
    private onTouched = (): void => { /**/};
    public autoCompleteValue: any;

    public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    public writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (this.dataKey?.length > 0) {
            this.autoCompleteValue = this.suggestions.filter((item: any) => item[this.dataKey] === value)[0];
        } else {
            this.autoCompleteValue = value;
        }
    }

    public select(selectedValue: any): void {
        const newValue: any = this.dataKey?.length > 0 ? selectedValue[this.dataKey] : selectedValue;
        this.onSelect.emit(newValue);
        this.onChange(newValue);
    }
}
```

You can then use your custom component, everywhere you use `<p-autoComplete ..>` you can replace it by `<mb-autoComplete ..>` (of course except in the html of `AutoCompleteComponent` where you must keep `<p-autoComplete ..>`).